# Fundamental theorem of calculus integration

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and that $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and its derivative is continuous on $[a,b]$ with $f'(t)\geq 0$ for each $t\in [a,b]$. Prove that there exists $c \in  [a,b]$ such that $$\int_a^b f(t)g(t)\,dt=f(a)\int_a^c g(t)\,dt+f(b)\int_c^b g(t)\,dt.$$

Any help to do this please.

Comment: it's a version of mean value theorem for integrals. also - use latex in your questions, makes them much easier to read

Comment: And [here's a reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Second_mean_value_theorem_for_integration).

Comment: Let $G$ be an antiderivate of $g$. Apply integration by parts to $\int_a^b f(t)g(t)\,dt$ with $u=f$ and $dv=g(t)\,dt$. Apply [this](http://planetmath.org/node/39604) to the term $\int_a^b f'(t)G(t)\,dt$.

Comment: I took G(x)=$\int_a^xg(t) dt$.Then I get f(b)$\int_a^b g(b)dt$-$\int_a^b f'(t)G(t)$.I don't get what should be done to $\int_a^b f'(t)G(t)$

Comment: Integration by parts gives $[G(b)f(b)-G(a)f(a)]-\int_a^b f'(t)G(t)\, dt$. Using the result in the link of my last comment (taking $f'$ to be  the "$g$" there), you have $\int_a^b f'(t)G(t)\,dt=G(c)\int_a^b f'(x)\,dx=G(c)(f(b)-f(a))$ for some $a<c<b$. Substitute and simplify to obtain your result.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
F(x) = f(a) \int_a^x g(t)\, dt + f(b) \int_x^b g(t)\, dt
      = \int_a^x f(a) g(t)\, dt + \int_x^b f(b) g(t)\, dt
$$
since $f(t)$ is increasing you have
$$
F(a) = \int_a^b f(b)g(t)\, dt \ge \int_a^b f(t)g(t)\, dt \ge  \int_a^b f(a)g(t)\, dt = F(b)
$$
and since $F$ is continuous, by the intermediate values theorem you get that there exists $c\in[a,b]$ satisfying the desired result.

Comment: Don't you need $g$ to be non-negative here?

Comment: If $f\ge g$ then $\int f \ge \int g$ no matter if $f$ and $g$ are positive or not.

Comment: Yes. But if $g$ is negative, you don't have $f(b)g(t)\ge f(t)g(t)$.

Comment: you're right...